# Neo4j-admin load dump.file returning: Not a valid Neo4j archive

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-aura

The dump comes from exporting a snapshot from AuraDB, as stated in Neo4j documentation.
im working with Neo4j Community 4.1.11 in Ubuntu, none of the other answers i found have been helpful...
Let me know what other piece of info you need to assess better the situation, thanks
when running the command...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may need to upgrade your local version of Neo4j to something much more recent - an Aura database I just created couldn't be loaded into any version of Neo4j older than 4.4.1 (as at current date).

However, the specific version you need to use will change over time.
[Guidance on the Aura support site](https://aura.support.neo4j.com/hc/en-us/articles/4402057623187-Loading-locally-to-Neo4j-on-prem-with-a-Dump-from-Aura-) indicates as much, and recommends using the latest possible local version of Neo4j as the target for the import (potentially to the point of needing to use pre-release versions), since Aura will typically be running bleeding-edge versions of the database store format.

An alternative might be to explore exporting to CSV or JSON and importing that way, since this output won't vary depending on Neo4j version of the source or target - you can do a stream-based export from Aura using `apoc.export.csv.all` or `apoc.export.json.all` which you could then load via script, though with large graphs this may not be practical.

Comment: To export json from Aura you can use the following query
`CALL apoc.export.json.all(null, {useTypes:true, stream: true});`